# Rotating point objects toward lines using QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a set of points that I'd like to have rotated toward nearest line by adding an attribute column `angle`.

[image: Original points with no rotation]
Original points with no rotation

[image: Points rotated to line object]
Points rotated toward line object

I have found and tweaked [this script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/178714/9073) to somewhat achieve what I want. The only problem is that this method only does a search using a rectangular box which sometimes gives me a less satisfying result. Is there a way to do the search using a circle instead?

Here's my tweaked script:

```py
from math import atan2

# get layers
buildings = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('buildings')[0]
roads = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('roads')[0]

# create angle field
fieldname = "angle"
buildings.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(fieldname,QVariant.Int)])
buildings.updateFields()

# get fieldindex
fni = buildings.fields().indexFromName('angle')

# initializations
tolerance = 30  # search tolerance
buildings.startEditing()

# loop over all buildings
for building in buildings.getFeatures():
    x = building.geometry().asPoint().x()
    y = building.geometry().asPoint().y()

    # get the rectangular search area 
    searchRect = QgsRectangle(x - tolerance, y - tolerance,  x + tolerance, y + tolerance)

    # find roads 
    for road in roads.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(searchRect)):
        # get the nearest vertex on road and the one before and after
        pnt, v, b, a, d = road.geometry().closestVertex(building.geometry().asPoint())
        p1 = road.geometry().vertexAt(v)
        # when vertex before exists look back, otherwise look forward
        if v>-1 and b>-1:
            p2 = road.geometry().vertexAt(b)
        elif v>-1 and a>-1:
            p2 = road.geometry().vertexAt(a)

        # calculate azimuth
        angle = atan2(p2.x() - p1.x(), p2.y() - p1.y()) / 0.017453
        building[fni] = angle
        buildings.updateFeature(building)

# save changes and stop editing
buildings.commitChanges()
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/428385/rotating-point-layer-according-to-line-layer-in-qgis/428391#428391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will give you more satisfactory results than what you are currently using, but I had a play around with some test data and came up with the following script which you are welcome to try. Instead of using a search rectangle or radius, it simply calculates the rotation from the azimuth of the nearest segment of the nearest line feature for each point feature.

```py
# get layers
buildings = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('buildings')[0]
roads = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('roads')[0]

# create angle field
fieldname = "angle"
buildings.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(fieldname,QVariant.Int)])
buildings.updateFields()

# get fieldindex
fni = buildings.fields().indexFromName('angle')

# build spatial index on roads layer
index = QgsSpatialIndex(roads.getFeatures(), flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries)

att_map = {}

# loop over all buildings
for building in buildings.getFeatures():
    # find nearest road feature to current building
    closest_feature_ids = index.nearestNeighbor(building.geometry())
    if closest_feature_ids:
        if len(closest_feature_ids) == 1:
            closest_feature = roads.getFeature(closest_feature_ids[0])
        else:
            nearest_points = [f.geometry().nearestPoint(building.geometry()) for f in roads.getFeatures(closest_feature_ids)]
            closest = [QgsGeometry.collectGeometry(nearest_points).nearestPoint(building.geometry())][0]
            closest_feature = [f for f in roads.getFeatures(closest_feature_ids) if f.geometry().intersects(closest.buffer(0.001, 8))][0]
    # find closest line segment of road feature
    a, b, c, d = closest_feature.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext(building.geometry().asPoint())
    # get azimuth of line from vertices before and after closest segment
    azimuth = closest_feature.geometry().vertexAt(c).azimuth(closest_feature.geometry().vertexAt(c-1))
    # create attribute map of feature ids, field index and azimuth value
    att_map[building.id()] = {fni: azimuth}

# update attribute values in buildings layer
buildings.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(att_map)
```

Before:

[image]

After (with marker rotation using data-defined values from 'angle' field):

[image]

You can also try this slightly different script which does not use a spatial index so it will be slower on large datasets but may give a more satisfactory result (I don't know).

```py
# get layers
buildings = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('buildings')[0]
roads = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('roads')[0]

# create angle field
fieldname = "angle"
buildings.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(fieldname,QVariant.Int)])
buildings.updateFields()

# get fieldindex
fni = buildings.fields().indexFromName('angle')

att_map = {}

# loop over all buildings
for building in buildings.getFeatures():
    # find nearest road feature to current building
    nearest_points = [f.geometry().nearestPoint(building.geometry()) for f in roads.getFeatures()]
    closest = [QgsGeometry.collectGeometry(nearest_points).nearestPoint(building.geometry())][0]
    closest_feature = [f for f in roads.getFeatures() if f.geometry().intersects(closest.buffer(0.001, 8))][0]
    # find closest line segment of road feature
    a, b, c, d = closest_feature.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext(building.geometry().asPoint())
    # get azimuth of line from vertices before and after closest segment
    azimuth = closest_feature.geometry().vertexAt(c).azimuth(closest_feature.geometry().vertexAt(c-1))
    # create attribute map of feature ids, field index and azimuth value
    att_map[building.id()] = {fni: azimuth}

# update attribute values in buildings layer
buildings.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(att_map)
```

Comment: This looks very promising! I tried the script and most features gets rotated right but some doesn't. Do you have a clue? Have a look here: https://imgur.com/a/Ix1O3bq

Comment: I read now [this](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/other/QgsSpatialIndex.html#qgis.core.QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor): "The nearest neighbour test is performed based on the feature bounding boxes only, so for non-point geometry features this method is not guaranteed to return the actual closest neighbours." So instead of using a rectangular box around the point, this script uses a rectangular box around the line feature instead. I wonder if there is another way to find the nearest line feature from a point?

Comment: @oskarlin, I have edited my answer slightly (construct the spatial index with `FlagStoreFeatureGeometries` flag) and also added a slightly different script version which would be slower on large datasets but may work better for you. Please try again with both.

Comment: I tried the first script again after your changes and it works very well. Thank you so much!

Comment: @oskarlin, that's great! I'm very glad to hear it worked for you.